# Combining Two Tables and Working with the Results

Tags: php, multiple-tables

I have two tables (Courses, and Enrollment). What I need to do is compare them and perform an action based on my results. Both tables contain the column "CourseID".

Courses (Table A) shows the user a full list of the courses available.  Enrollment (Table B) is a list of courses the user is already enrolled in.

In a nutshell, I need to compare the "CourseID" columns, and if "CourseID" appears in both tables, then I want to echo the word "registered" next to the CourseID in Table A.

I've tried using  Arrays, For Loops, While Loops, Foreach Loops, Joins, Unions, DISTINCT ... everything I could think of but I can't get it to work. I'm at my wits end with this situation.

I'm pretty new at using PHP, so any help someone can provide would be extremely helpful. (Providing an example with an explanation would really help as well.)

Thank you in advance for the help.

Edited:

I apologize for not showing any code.  For the "Courses" table (Table A) I'm using a While Loop as shown below:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Courses WHERE Active = 'Yes' ORDER BY CourseID ASC";

$result = mysql_query($query)
              or die ("Could Not Execute Query.");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{

extract($row);

echo" // --- HTML CODE --- // ";

}
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, what the output should be, and what the DB system you are using is (mysql, mssql, etc.). Also showing some of your attempts could help so we don't redo attempt you already made.

Comment: To add to user's comment ... Post YOUR example code of what you have done. For us to "provide an example" is too close to a code-writing service. You will get far more mileage showing your efforts.

Comment: @user3783243.  I am working with PHP and using the mysql DB.  I have included my code for the "Courses" table (Table A) and using a while loop to generate the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't provide any code, which makes this little harder, but I think something like this could work.

Store to $courses variable

```
SELECT CourseID FROM Courses;
```

Store to $enrollments variable

```
SELECT CourseID FROM Enrollment WHERE UserID = 1;
```

Then you can easily show which courses user has already picked

```
foreach ($courses as $courseId) {
    if (in_array($courseId, $enrollments)) {
        // already joined course
    } else {
        // show in available list 
    }
}
```

This is very simple example but this can be done with one sql query also.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work for me.  I've gone back and included some code in my post to try to clarify what I'm using.  I'm using a while loop with my Courses table (Table A). I'm wondering if that has any impact on the results since I use a while loop with this table.

Comment: I just wanted to thank you for your help.  I was able to use this code to fix the problem that I was having.  I removed my original while loop and replaced it with your example code using a new query in the "if" and "else" condition.  It all works perfectly now!  Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want to accomplish can be done with a `left join` and a dual `on` statement. (The `CASE` is just to make it easier to read)

Something like this should do it:

```
select a.name, 
case 
  when b.courseid is null then
    'Not Enrolled'
  else
    'Enrolled'
  end
from courses as a
left join enrolled as b
on a.courseid = b.courseid 
and b.userid = 1
```

Since sample data wasn't provided I've made up my own samples and created this demo that can show the usage: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8d8751/1